# JScrollPane problems, not appearing

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have added a few components to my `JTextPane` and everything prints out fine but when I want to print out more, my `JScrollPane` does not show up so that I can scroll down to see the other components.

```
int p=0;
    int y1=0;
    int y2=20;
    int i=0;
 while (i< 10){    
    JLabel date= new JLabel();
    date.setSize(100, 21);
    date.setText("date posted");

    JLabel username= new JLabel();
    username.setSize(100,21);
    username.setText("username");

    JLabel picture= new JLabel();
    picture.setSize(120, 120);
    try {
        ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(scaleImage(120, 120, ImageIO.read(new 
    File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ProfilePicture.png"))));
        picture.setIcon(ii);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JTextArea caption= new JTextArea();
    caption.setText("caption here...");
    caption.setLineWrap(true);
    caption.setEditable(false);
    caption.setSize(100, 100);
    JScrollPane CaptionScroll = new JScrollPane (caption, 
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    CaptionScroll.setSize(100,100);

    JTextArea comments= new JTextArea();
    comments.setText("comments here...");
    comments.setLineWrap(true);
    comments.setSize(100, 100);
    JScrollPane CommentScroll = new JScrollPane (comments, 
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    CommentScroll.setSize(100,100);

    JButton CommentButton= new JButton();
    CommentButton.setText("Submit");
    CommentButton.setSize(100, 21);
    CommentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //do stufff
        }
    });

    likes=0;
    final JLabel likeLabel= new JLabel();
    likeLabel.setText("LIKES: "+ Integer.toString(likes));
    likeLabel.setSize(100,21);

    final JButton LikeButton= new JButton();
    LikeButton.setText("Like");
    LikeButton.setSize(100, 21);
    LikeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (liked == false) {
                likes++;
                likeLabel.setText("LIKES: "+ Integer.toString(likes));
                LikeButton.setText("UnLike");
                liked=true;
            }
            else{
                likes--;
                likeLabel.setText("LIKES: "+ Integer.toString(likes));
                LikeButton.setText("Like");
                liked=false;
            }
        }
    });

    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(username, p).setLocation(125, y1);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(CaptionScroll,p).setLocation(120, y2);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(CommentButton,p).setLocation(230,y1);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(CommentScroll, p).setLocation(230, y2);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(LikeButton,p).setLocation(340, y1);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(likeLabel,p).setLocation(340, y2);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(date,p).setLocation(450, y1);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.add(picture, p).setLocation(0, y1);
    p++;
    DMInboxOutputTextPane.repaint();
    i++;
    y1=y1+130;
    y2=y2+130;
}
```

I am able to print three of the objects i want printed but after that everything else gets cut off and the scrollPane does not appear.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct, others are not. Be consistent. Don't use a null layout. Don't use setSize() and setLocation(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Scrolling will only work when the preferred size of a panel is calculated properly, which is one of the functions of the layout manager.

Comment: I am not completely sure how to do this with a JTextPane

Comment: What is DMInboxOutputTextPane? Can you show where this component is added into the GUI?

Comment: The DMInboxOutputTextPane is a JTextPane

Comment: `jScrollPane8.setViewportView(DMInboxOutputTextPane);

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout InboxPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(InboxPanel);
        InboxPanel.setLayout(InboxPanelLayout);`

Comment: `InboxPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            InboxPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane8)
            .addGroup(InboxPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(200, 200, 200)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addContainerGap(263, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );`

Comment: `InboxPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            InboxPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, InboxPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 397, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jScrollPane8.getViewport().add(DMInboxOutputTextPane);`

Comment: @Sharcoux he is where the DMInboxOutputTextPane is add to the GUI

Comment: @camickr any clue?

Comment: I already gave you my suggestions. A JTextPanel is for displaying text. I have no idea what your code is attempting to do, You don't add components to a text pane. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information on text panes. Don't post code in a comment. Nobody can read that. When you ask a question post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You actually CAN use a JTextPane to hold components. The question is more about if it is a good idea. Could you edit your post and provide an explanation about why you are using a JTextPane (what is your ultimate goal), and a piece of code that we could use to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @Sharcoux i actually remade this part of my code and it works now, but my end goal for the code was to be able to add multiple "post" and each "post" has the same layout/components just different data. Thank you for your help! If you know any neat ways of doing something like this, I'd still love to hear them for the next time I make something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, for this kind of things, you add your components in a JPanel layed out with a vertical BoxLayout. Something like:

```
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

You can set your pane scrollable like that:

```
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pane);
```

Given your usecase, you might need to implements the Scrollable interface to get more control over your scrollPane:

```
public static class VerticalScrollablePane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {
    public VerticalScrollablePane(LayoutManager layout) {super(layout);}
    public VerticalScrollablePane() {}
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {return getPreferredSize();}
    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        switch(orientation) {
        case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
            return visibleRect.height / 10;
        case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
            return visibleRect.width / 10;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid orientation: " + orientation);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        switch(orientation) {
        case SwingConstants.VERTICAL:
            return visibleRect.height;
        case SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL:
            return visibleRect.width;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid orientation: " + orientation);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {return false;}

}
```

You would then have:

```
    JPanel pane = new VerticalScrollablePane();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pane);
```

Hope it helped!